# Style Intellisense Not Working in VS Code When Language Mode Set To Vue

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vuetify.js

When I am editing a file with the Vue extension in VS Code I do not get Syle intellisense in the HTML. If I change the Language Mode to HTML then it works but I no longer get Vue intellisense.

Is there a way to make this work in a Vue file?

[image: VSCode Mode]

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, you can install the following extension: [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur). It has great features like linting, formatting, snippets and of course syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks, but I have it installed.